# Easy way to temporarily insulate gap between hardwood floor and baseboard?

Tags: insulation

Odors are entering my apartment from a neighboring unit, and it appears to be getting in via a draft between the baseboard and hardwood floor in my apartment. The draft appears to be localized to a small area in my living room. I'd like to put something in between the baseboard and the floor to insulate the gap. Is there anything I can use that will provide good insulation but be easy to remove without damaging the baseboard or floor? The gap is about 1/8".

Also, if I did talk to my landlord about permanently filling the gap, what is the recommended way to do this with hardwood floors?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: The way the gap is typically dealt with is setting shoe mold. It won't necessarily seal the gap, the purpose of it is to cover the gap, so it is not an eyesore from the movement of the base during seasonal humidity changes.

Comment: I added a photo. Many areas in my apartment have a similar gap, but I'm only getting drafts in a few places (I used a stick of burning incense to check for airflow), so I think I could get away with only putting insulation in select spots.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "seal and peel" type removable weatherstripping caulk.

Some type of caulk would probably be the permanent solution as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I'd heard that caulk was generally not recommended between hardwood floors and baseboards.

Comment: @brandondtb, could be. I'd check the caulk for any material restrictions. I used the removable caulk on old painted wood window frames, and some paint did chip off when removing it, but I'd suspect that wouldn't happen if the baseboard paint is in relatively good condition.

Answer (score 3):

There is a polyurethane foam [rope-like insulation](http://www.homedepot.com/s/caulk%2520saver?NCNI-5) used to fill gaps before adding caulk

[image: rope insulation]

This comes in various sizes from 3/8" to 5"8. It can be compressed to about 1/4 of its diameter. It also should be removable, if need be.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only and not an endorsement of products or sources.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a concern about potential damage I would use "Moretite". It is a clay like material. It comes in a roll of various diameters.It is inexpensive and somewhat reusable.  You can wrap several pieces together for larger gaps. I have never had issues with paint damage or residue after removal